# Angular get data using http service and map the data

Tags: angular-httpclient

l'm trying to get the data "pnfiles" from the API and map the data, if l test the api in post man it return the following JSON data

```
{
"DataResult": {
    "4562": {
        "pnData": {
            "pnID": "4562",
            "userID": "2427",
            "storeID": "8",
            "supplierID": "1119",
            "skuID": "C123-ZA-SI-NE",
            "deptID": "",
            "categoryID": "",
            "note": "Sale",
            "priority": "0",
            "deviceCreatedTS": "2021-06-22 19:13:35",
            "loadedTS": "2021-06-22 19:13:35",
            "linkedID": "0",
            "dataDate": "2021-06-10",
            "channelCode": "18",
            "flagID": "7",
            "geoLat": "0.00000000",
            "geoLong": "0.00000000",
            "geoAcc": "0",
            "articleDescription": "117 - Citiz & Milk Silver",
            "userName": "Christopher Steven Ogle",
            "lastSeen": "unread",
            "flagDescription": "Sale",
            "flagType": "0"
        },
        "pnfiles": [
            {
                "fID": "1323",
                "pnID": "4562",
                "fileName": "IMG_20210620_113839_1.jpg",
                "filePath": "../PhotoNoteStore/2021-06-22/4562/1323-IMG_20210620_113839_1.jpg",
                "loadedTS": "2021-06-22 19:13:35",
                "dateModified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "fID": "1324",
                "pnID": "4562",
                "fileName": "IMG_20210620_113822.jpg",
                "filePath": "../PhotoNoteStore/2021-06-22/4562/1324-IMG_20210620_113822.jpg",
                "loadedTS": "2021-06-22 19:13:35",
                "dateModified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
 }
```

the following is the service where l'm trying to get the data and map the data or just console log it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GalleryService {

url = environment.url;

constructor(
  private http: HttpClient,
) {}

suppliergallery(id) {
return this.http.get(`${this.url}/V2/api/something/?gallery/?supplier=${id}`).pipe(
  map(results => {
      console.log("result in galleryservice",results);
      return results['DataResult']['pnfiles'];
    })
 );
}
```

}

can someone assist me if the way l'm getting the data is wrong, the below result is from the console log

```
result in galleryservice 
Object { DataResult: {…} }
```

​
DataResult: Object { LinkedSuppliers: false, LinkedSuppliersCount: 1 }
​​
LinkedSuppliers: false
​​
LinkedSuppliersCount: 1
​​
: Object { … }

Answer (score 0):

this question can be closed, my bug was coming from the api itself